# bash: integer expression expected

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I have a file out.csv I have to check if the name inputed by user exists in the file(comma separated) or not. I am taking name using read but while checking for equality I am getting error

```
    IFS=","
    while read tname tnum
        do
            if [ $tname -eq $name ]; then
                flag=1
                break
            fi
        done < out.csv
    echo "$ch"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're getting this error since you are trying to compare string using equality operators intended for integers, `-eq`, `-ne`, `-gt`, and similar are integer functions.

To compare strings use `=` to compare for equality OR `!=` to compare for non-equality.

Check [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) for more on comparison operators.

```
if [ $tname -eq $name ]; then
```

should be changed to:

```
if [ "$tname" = "$name" ]; then
```

(also remember to quote your variables).

Comment: if [ $tname = $name ]; then 
also works what difference will it make if we add inverted commas(like "$tname")

Comment: @user2179293 Without quotes, the value of each variable is interpreted as a whitespace-separated list of glob patterns. With double quotes, the value of each variable is interpreted as a string. If you don't understand this, keep it simple: always put double quotes around variable substitutions, i.e. `[ "$tname" = "$name" ]`. Leave off the quotes only if you've read [When is double-quoting necessary?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary/68748#68748) and remember all the rules and hate the next person who will maintain that script.